# Transparency in EPS -- does pdfmark work?

Tags: graphics, transparency, eps

I'm trying to implement an export to EPS feature (in C++), and I'm using the pdfmark [(pdf)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfmark_reference.pdf) extensions for transparency, but I have yet to see them have any effect. I'm using Illustrator 14.0 and GSView 4.9 as clients. Even using this example from Adobe's docs produces no transparency.

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: xan
%%Pages: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 600 600
%%EndComments
%%Page: 1 1
/DeviceCMYK setcolorspace 15 setlinewidth
[ /ca .6 /CA .3 /BM /Normal /SetTransparency pdfmark
0 1 1 0 setcolor 220 330 150 0 360 arc fill % red
0 0 1 0 setcolor 320 503 150 0 360 arc fill % yellow
1 1 0 0 setcolor 420 330 150 0 360 arc fill % blue
1 0 0 0 setcolor 230 440 104 0 360 arc stroke   % cyan
0 1 0 0 setcolor 410 440 104 0 360 arc stroke   % magenta
0 0 1 0 setcolor 320 284 104 0 360 arc stroke   % yellow
%%EOF
```

Is there another flag I need to set? Or is it just a problem with these clients?

Comment: Update: Mac Preview.app also seems to ignore pdfmark transparency.

Comment: Are you expecting to see the transparency in a PostScript viewer? I don't think this will work. You have to convert the EPS into a PDF. The PDF viewers then should display the transparency, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that using `pdfmark` for transparency does work in Adobe Distiller (which converts EPS to PDF) if you replace

```
/AllowTransparency false
```

with

```
/AllowTransparency true
```

in the `.joboptions` settings file.